# How to increase render preview bounces? (Cycles in viewport)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, light

Even increasing the amount of bounces in Render > Light Paths > Max Bounces, the preview of the viewport does not increase light. When I render the image the scene is much more brighter.

[image: Different bounces in preview and final render.]

My scene is clean, no hidden lights in the viewport. I also did not change the exposure in Film.

[image: Values ​​look normal.]

Why is there such a difference? How to have a more accurate preview?

Thank you.

Comment: The bounces control should be shared. Are you letting the preview reach the full 128 samples before comparing? At low samples counts adding more samples can noticeably change the brightness of the scene, that may be what you're seeing here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It was actually Simplify that was limiting the viewport's AO bounces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a cause of the problem. ***Simplify*** is active and limiting the number of *Ambient Occlusion bouces* in the viewport. I just match the values ​​to get a similar render.

[image]